# Lyapunov function for a compettive Lotka-Volterra system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have this dynamical system in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

> \begin{aligned}
> \dot{x}&=x \left( 1-x-\frac{1}{3} y\right)\\
> \dot{y}&=y \left( \frac{3}{4}-y-\frac{1}{2}x  \right)
> \end{aligned}

I found where $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ are $0$ and the nature of these points, after that I studied the global dynamical of the system now; I have to show that every points s.t. $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ are $0$ in that point is asymptotically stable in the future using an appropriate Lyapunov function, and then discuss the evolution (in the future) of a generic ($x_0$,$y_0$) with both $x_0$ and $y_0$ > $0$.

I really have a problem in finding the Lyapunov, anybody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: " I have to show that every points s.t. dxdt and dydt are 0 in that point is asymptotically stable" Difficult to show this since only one fixed point amongst four is stable, the others being all instable.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka–Volterra_equations) unhelpful??

Comment: [And further](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka–Volterra_equations#Lyapunov_functions).